# HTML Email Newsletter Generator from Wordpress, Joomla or any CMS for that matter

Tags: html, wordpress, joomla, content-management-system, newsletter

Does anybody know of an add-on for Wordpress, Joomla or any CMS that will automatically 'fill' a html email newsletter template.

Here's my proposed work flow:

> 1. User adds articles to CMS
> 2. CMS add-on generates/fills pre designed html email template
> 3. Email template is exported ready to be imported into Mailchimp, Campaign Monitor or the like.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are add ons on wordpress to send newsletter from wordpress but there is no integration for that.